# SerialPort.ReadLine() does not read data from USB COM port sent by Arduino

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I'm sending textual data to COM15 (via micro USB) using Arduino. On my desktop, I'm trying to read the data from my C# application. However, when I run it, the console simply shows nothing and the program stucks at the line "string s = myPort.ReadLine()".

The following is my C# program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myPort = new SerialPort("COM15", 115200);
    myPort.Open();
    while (true)
    {
        var s = myPort.ReadLine(); // execution stucks here waiting forever!
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

The following is the Arduino code (sends data to COM15):

```
int counter = 1;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
 Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
Serial.println(" Data Loop = " + String(counter));
counter++;
delay(500);
}
```

The arduino serial monitor does show the data being received at COM15. I also tried other software that read COM ports and verified that the data is available at the port.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By adding the following line before myPort.Open() command, I managed to fix my issue and read from the COM successfully:

```
myPort.DtrEnable = true;
```

You may ask what is Dtr flag. Dtr stands for "Data Terminal Ready" and according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Terminal_Ready):

> Data Terminal Ready (DTR) is a control signal in RS-232 serial
>   communications, transmitted from data terminal equipment (DTE), such
>   as a computer, to data communications equipment (DCE), for example a
>   modem, to indicate that the terminal is ready for communications and
>   the modem may initiate a communications channel.